# не загружается картинка

Tags: yii2

вот контролер

```
     <?php

    namespace backend\controllers;

    use Yii;
    use common\models\User;
    use app\models\UserSearch;
    use yii\web\Controller;
    use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
    use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
    use yii\web\UploadedFile;
    use yii\filters\AccessControl;

     public function actionUpdate($id)
        {
            $model = $this->findModel($id);
           if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
                $auth = Yii::$app->getAuthManager();
                $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
                $role = $auth->getRole($post['role']);
               $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'avatar');
               $name=$model->file->baseName.''.$model->file->extension;
               $years=date('Y');
               $mounts=date('m');
               if (file_exists('foto/'.$years.'/'.$mounts.'/')){} else{
                   mkdir(Yii::getAlias('@backend/web/').'foto/'.$years.'/'.$mounts.'/', 0775, true);
               }
               $model->file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@backend/web/').'foto/'.$years.'/'.$mounts.'/'.$name.'.'.$model->file->extension);
               $path=Yii::getAlias('@backend/web/').'foto/'.$years.'/'.$mounts.'/'.$name.'.'.$model->file->extension;
               $model->avatar=$path;
               if($model->save()){
                   $auth->revokeAll($id);
                    $auth->assign($role, $id);}
           return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
       } else {
                return $this->render('update', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'auth' => Yii::$app->authManager->roles,
                    'read' => $role
                ]);
           }
        } 

вот модель
```

```
use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

/**
 * User model
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $password_hash
 * @property string $password_reset_token
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $auth_key
 * @property integer $status
 * @property integer $created_at
 * @property integer $updated_at
 * @property string $password write-only password
 */
class User extends ActiveRecord implements
    \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    public $files;
    const ROLE_USER = 'user';
    const ROLE_ADMIN = 'admin';
    const ROLE_MODER = 'moder';
    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%user}}';
    }


  вот вид 



<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('Логин') ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'password_hash')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('Пароль') ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'password_reset_token')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('Повторить пароль') ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('Е-mail') ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'status')->textInput() ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'avatar')->fileInput()->label('Установите картинку аватара') ?>
        <?php if($model->isNewRecord){ ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'created_at')->hiddenInput(['value'=>$theDate])->label('') ?>
        <?php }else{ ?>
            <div class="form-group field-category-parent_id">
                <label class="control-label" for="auth-role">Выберите роль</label>
                <?= Html::dropDownList('role',0,$role,$option=['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'auth-role'])?>
            </div>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'id')->hiddenInput(['value'=>$model->id])->label('') ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'updated_at')->hiddenInput(['value'=>$theDate])->label('') ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'auth_key')->hiddenInput(['maxlength' => true,'value'=>$authKey])->label('') ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Создать' : 'Изменить', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>
```

пишет Setting unknown property: common\models\User::file и ругается на эту строку

```
$model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'avatar');
```

не подскажите в чем проблема ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ошибке указано на модель User, а вы хотите работать с моделью Image.
Т.е. $model в данном случае в контроллере - User.

Comment: ой не ту модель выложил сейчас поменял

Comment: опять же, в модели у вас $files, сетить вы пытаетесь в $model->file